# Query Using Group By for multiple columns with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the table

```
account_no | name | date        | amount 
1101       |   A  |  2018-11-20 |  50
1101       |   A  |  2018-11-20 |  20
1102       |   B  |  2018-11-20 |  30    
1101       |   A  |  2018-11-19 |  100
1101       |   A  |  2018-11-18 |  80
1102       |   B  |  2018-11-19 |  70
```

And the I want the following output

```
account_no | name  | group(today) | group(month)
1101       |   A   |     70       |  250 
1102       |   B   |     30       |  100
```

either I am getting today's sum or month's sum not both in a single row.
What I have tried so far

```
select account_no, sum(today) from account group by account_no having date = '<today>'

select account_no, sum(today) from account group by account_no having date between '<firstDay>' and '<today>'
```

I can think of using UNION ALL but giving duplicate rows.

Comment: You could show a bit of effort and publish what you have done so far. If you don't know where to start search for mysql conditional aggregation.

Comment: what is the today mean?

Comment: today means currenDate - Here I want currentDate sum and whole month till today sum

Comment: But your expected output is not same as your sample data - for A there is only 50 for currentdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select account_no,name, sum(case when yourdate='<today>' then amount end) as sumoftoday,
sum(amount) for sumofmonth
from tablename
where yourdate between '<firstDay>' and '<today>'
group by account_no,name
```

Comment: It worked like a Charm. Thanks a Million. I did another work around. Just have a look. But your's is Optimum.

Comment: Select account_no, name, sum(today_total) as Today, sum(month_total) as Month From ( 
    Select account_no, name, sum(amount) as today_total, null as month_total from account where date>=<today> group by account_no
    UNION ALL
    Select account_no, name, null as today_total, sum(amount) as month_total from account where date between <firstDay> and <today> group by account_no
) as t1 group by account_no

Comment: @Abdul, this will work too - since you can do it in a single query, so that is the more optimum

Comment: Yes @fa06 you are right. your solution is more optimum. Thanks once again. You saved my day. My project demands more complex queries like this. Now I found the way. will play with.